# bootstrap - Buttons not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ul with the classes of `"nav nav-tabs nav-stacked"` this has a li and a `"<a>"` inside it and inside the `"<a>"` there are two button with the classes of `"pull-right btn btn-primary"`. What's happening is that the button are sticking to the bottom of the list item I want them to be in the middle of list item.

For more clearance here is the:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="margin-top: 60px;">
            <?php
            $all_connections = get_user_connection_requests($_SESSION["uid"]);
            while($connection = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_connections)) {
                echo "<li><a>{$connection["fName"]} {$connection['lName']}"
            ?>
            <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary ">Accept</button>
            <button class="pull-right btn btn-danger ">Deny</button>
            <?php echo "</a></li>"; }   ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</div>
```

**The Output:**
[image]

[Full Size Image Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxsiP.png)

I want the buttons to be also in the middle like the text.

How can I do this?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)**

Comment: What happens if you put the buttons *before* the text?

Comment: I can't do that becuase the LIs are dynamically printed and secondly I don't want that type of layout! @ExplosionPills

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle?

Comment: No I can't becuase jsfiddle has no support or library for twitter bootstrap :( @MiljanPuzović

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui, you have option External Resources in jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah I know, but bootstrap is only downloaded,, it's not like jQuery(can be downloaded + can be linked) @MiljanPuzović

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui, below is my answer. And yes, you can link Bootstrap files from source code of Twitter Bootstrap site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .button-group{margin-top:-5px}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="margin-top: 60px;">

            <li>
                <a>
                    Mohammad Danish
                    <div class="pull-right button-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary ">Accept</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger ">Deny</button>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes on your code, because floating elements can make some trouble.

First I've added id `#something` to `ul` list just to fix floating issue. And then I've added `<span class="centered">` to wrap text inside your anchor tag.

Here is CSS

```
#something li a {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

And here is edited HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <ul id="something" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="margin-top: 60px;">
            <li>
               <a href="">
                  <span class="centered">sssss</span>
                  <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary ">Accept</button>
                  <button class="pull-right btn btn-danger ">Deny</button>
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A9Qau/)**